# Create backup table concatenated with sysdate before deleting the rows in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a package and defined a procedure to delete specific rows retrieved by the cursor.
Before the rows were deleted from the table, I want to take a backup of those records every time the package is compiled and I need the backup table to be created as tablename concatenated with sysdate.

ex: if table name is emp, backup table should be created as emp_2020_10_16

Below is the sample code I have created:

```
PROCEDURE DELETE_REC(
    P_retcode      NUMBER,
    P_errorbuff    VARCHAR2,
    P_unit_id       NUMBER,
    P_join_date VARCHAR2
)
IS
  
  CURSOR cur1
  IS
     SELECT unit_ID,dept_ID,join_DATE
FROM EMP MMT
WHERE MMT.dep_TYPE_ID IN (44,35)
AND MMT.unit_id       = P_unit_id
AND MMT.join_date      < to_date(P_join_date,'RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');

      
  
BEGIN

--begin
--      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Create table EMP_' || to_char(sysdate,'yyyy_mm_dd') || ' as select * from  EMP MMT WHERE MMT.dep_TYPE_ID IN (44,35)
AND MMT.unit_id       = P_unit_id
AND MMT.join_date      < to_date(P_join_date,'RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'); 
--      
--    end;
/*Here i would like to create backup table like above before executing the below delete statement but i am not sure about the correct standards that i should be using for above dynamic statement*/
  
FOR val IN cur1
    LOOP
           DELETE
FROM EMP MMT
WHERE MMT.dept_ID= val.dept_id;
```

How can I backup the table using above dynamic statement in best possible way? I am still learning PL&SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sth like this would help:

```
create table employees as select * from hr.employees;
--drop table emp_2020_10_18;
--drop table employees;

----------------
declare     
vTabName varchar2(50);     
nDept_id number := 10;     
nCnt number := 0;     
     
vSQL varchar2(1000);     
  
begin     
     
vTabName := 'emp_'||to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy_mm_dd');     
     
     
-- check if table exists     
begin     
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from emp_tmp'   into nCnt;      
exception when others then      
    nCnt := -1;     
end;     
     
-- if not exists create one     
if nCnt = -1 then     
    execute immediate 'create table '|| vTabName||' as select * from employees where 1=2'  ;   
   
end if;     
   
execute immediate 'insert into '|| vTabName ||'  select * from employees where department_id = :nDept_id' using nDept_id;

delete from employees where department_id = nDept_id;

exception when others then      
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);     
end; 
/
```